# Set up specific questions to appear only after particular answers on Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I am currently creating a survey using Google Forms. It's quite a long survey, so I would like to make it as quick as possible for everybody doing it.

A lot of the survey questions are repeated and depend on whether or not a person has had training in a particular area.

For example, the first question for each page will be:

> - Have you had training in X?

Followed by questions according to the first answer, e.g.

> - If you have not had training in X, how interested would you be in having training in X?
> - If you have had training in X, how confident are you in delivering the service?
> - Do you feel you have enough time to deliver the service?
> - etc.

Is it possible to create the survey so that if somebody indicates that they have or have not had training in X, it only shows them the follow-up question relevant to their experience?

Another advantage would be that I would increase the likelihood that the people are responding to every answer, and not just skipping over it. At the moment, I have to make the follow-up questions optional due to it applying/not applying to them, so it means they can skip over questions that are relevant to them.

Comment: Okay, I'm half-able to answer my question already...I just found out what I'm looking for is 'logic branching' and that google appears to offer this...will do more investigating while I wait for a response for anybody!http://googledocs.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/page-navigation-in-google-forms.html#!/2010/07/page-navigation-in-google-forms.html

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to create pages in your Google Form as well as relevant multiple choice questions to take you between these pages.

For each page you set up, they will correspond with a multiple choice selection.

1. Add a question type of **multiple choice**

   - You will see "Go to page based on answer" appear as a checkbox next to it. Click that.
     The following warning appears:

   > Note: "go to page" questions work only on forms with multiple pages. Choose "page break" from the Add Item menu to add additional pages.
2. For each of the answer choices you'll see a "Continue to next page" drop down selection.

   [image: jump selection between pages]

   - What they select here will determine if they skip a page and move right onto the next relevant section or continue as part of the normal flow.
3. To skip pages, look at the bottom of each page break section for the **After page X: Continue to next page** selection.

   [image: page jump or continue as normal]

   - Choose accordingly and you can have the respondent not have to go through questions only those that selected a certain answer previously needed to.

Here's an example of what you might set up:

```
+ Bowel movements
|
| X : Y : Z
|
+ Night terrors
|
| {Y & Z answers from Bowel movements; Continue on to A Brunch to Remember}
|
+ Morning regrets
|
| {Only show to X answers from Bowel movements}
|
+ A Brunch to Remember
|
|
```

If you selected X in the Bowel Movements section, you jump straight to Morning Regrets. Other answers will continue on to Night Terrors. Those that fill out Night Terrors do not need to answer any from the Morning Regrets page and will then continue on to A Brunch to Remember.