# One time check to see if document is shared with a specific user

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm trying to figure out how to write an Apps Script that checks "IF" a Google Drive URL is shared with a specific user. I do not want this to be a continuous check, just a "one time check".

**Example Sheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dfLpgTdS-8AFUiD5Z7sFJvLn0mMid3_00TrxhDVkXno/edit#gid=432338521

I need "column H" in the sheet above to check the URL in "column G" to see if it is shared (with edit rights) with a specific gmail account (tbenrud@guhsd.net). Not a continuous check, just a "one time check". If the URL is shared (with edit rights) I'd like to return a "yes" in "column H" and return a "no" if not.

This sheet is populated by a google form. I hope the "one time check" can be triggered on form submit, but I'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**CODE I'M EXPERIMENTING WITH**

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('responses');
  var range = sheet.getRange('G2:G'); //Gets the file URL
  var output = SHAREDWITHME(range.getValues()); //Checks each value on the selected range
  //Sets the results to the right of the selected range
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(output); 
}
/**
 * Check files IDs are from files shared with me
 *
 * @param {A1:A5} input The range with file IDs.
 * @return TRUE or FALSE
 * 
 */

function SHAREDWITHME(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(SHAREDWITHME) // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    try {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(input);
      return 'TRUE'
    } catch(e) {
      return 'FALSE';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the on form submit installable trigger.

Related Q&A

- [How do you create an installable trigger for a Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112123/88163)

Comment: thanks for helping. I'm unclear as to the Apps Script I need to use in conjunction to the installable trigger. I've added a sample of what I was experimenting with to my original question. Thank you for any additional help you can offer.